# CSS Overflow with Coda Slider

Tags: jquery, css, coda-slider

Im using the Coda Slider. If you don't know the Coda Slider, the `overflow-x` position is hidden until a tab is clicked. An animation then slides the hidden DIV in from the right or left.

If you scroll down one of the panels and click the tabs at the top again, it slides the tab over, but it doesn't change the `overflow` position.

Is there a way of controlling the `overflow-y` or even reset it to `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS 3 has the property overflow-y (and overflow-x).
They are not supported by older browsers like IE 7 and older Firefox, but certainly useful.

[CSS 3 Overflows-y/x](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html)

There are some great examples of how they behave.

jQuery has some nice features too:

[jQuery scrollTo info](http://flesler.blogspot.com/)

or for an example:

[Demo similar to the code slider](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/)

Hope that helps

Comment: overflow-x/y worked in IE7 and even IE6. It was actually introduced by MS, before being added to the CSS3 spec. You do have to be careful with using it because not all browser implement it the same.